# Asymptotic expansion of integral depending on a parameter

Tags: integration

I would like to find an equivalent (first term of an asymptotic expansion) of the following function in $x=0$ and $x=1$:

$$f(x)=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t^x\sqrt{1+t^2}}\ dt$$

My professor gave a highly unmotivated solution which doesn't invoke the usual tools to find asympto
tic expansions of integrals depending on some parameter.

I would be interested in an elementary, but motivated solution.

Comment: There is a difference between $\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} \frac 1 {t^x \sqrt{1+t^2}} \, dt$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty} \frac 1 {t^x \sqrt{1+t^2}} \, dx.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Herein we present a way forward, which relies on elementary analysis only, to derive the first three terms of the "small $x$" expansion of the function of interest.  To that end, we now proceed.**

---

For $x>0$, we have

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x\log(t)}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x\log(t)}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\,dt+\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-x\log(t)}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x\log(t)}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\,dt+\int_0^1 \frac{e^{x\log(t)}}{t\sqrt{t^2+1}}\,dt\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

The first term on the right-hand side of $(1)$ is well behaved near $x=0^+$ with

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x\log(t)}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\,dt&=\text{arsinh}(1)-x\int_0^1 \frac{\log(t)}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt+O(x^2)\\\\
&=\text{arsinh}(1)-x\int_0^{\pi/4} \log(\tan(\phi))\,\sec(\phi)\,d\phi+O(x^2)\tag2
\end{align}$$

---

The second term  on the right-hand side of $(1)$ can be written as

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{e^{x\log(t)}}{t\sqrt{t^2+1}}\,dt&=\int_0^1 \frac{e^{x\log(t)}}{t}\,dt-\int_0^1 \frac{e^{x\log(t)}}{t}\left(1-\left(1+t^2\right)^{-1/2}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\frac1x -\int_0^1 \frac{1-\left(1+t^2\right)^{-1/2}}{t}\,dt-x\int_0^1 \frac{(1-\left(1+t^2\right)^{-1/2})\,\log(t)}{t}\,dt+O(x^2)\\\\
&=\frac1x -\text{arsinh}(1)+\log(2)-x\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\tan(\phi))\,\sec(\phi)\frac{1-\cos(\phi)}{\sin(\phi)}\,d\phi+O(x^2)\tag3
\end{align}$$

---

Substituting $(2)$ and $(3)$ into $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac1x +\log(2) -x\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\tan(\phi))\,\sec(\phi)\left(1+\frac{1-\cos(\phi)}{\sin(\phi)}\right)\,d\phi+O(x^2)\\\\
&=\frac1x +\log(2) +\frac1{12}\left(\pi^2+6\log^2(2)\right)\,x+O(x^2)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a rather tedious calculation, so resorting to computer algebra we find (for $0 < x < 1$):

$f(x) = \frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\pi }}$.

[image: f(x)]

Notice that it is symmetric with respect to $x = 1/2$.

The first three terms in the expansion around $x=0$ are:

$f(x) \approx \frac{1}{x}+\log (2)+\frac{1}{12} x \left(\pi ^2+6 \log ^2(2)\right)+\frac{1}{12} x^2 \left(3 \zeta (3)+2
   \log ^3(2)+\pi ^2 \log (2)\right)+O\left(x^3\right)$

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is defined in $(0,1)$, and it's symmetric with respect to $x={1\over2}$ since
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{t^x\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt+\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t^x\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt\\
&=\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{t^x\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt+\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{s^{1-x}\sqrt{1+s^2}}ds\\
\end{align}
thus we can study on only one side, here we choose $x\to0^+$, then we have
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_0^{1} \frac{1}{s^{1-x}\sqrt{1+s^2}}ds+\operatorname{arsinh}(1)+o(1)\\
&=[{s^x\over x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}]_0^1+{1\over x}\int_0^{1}\frac{s^{x+1}}{(1+s^2)^{3/2}}ds+\ln(1+\sqrt{2})+o(1)\\
&={1\over \sqrt{2}x}+{1\over x}(1-{1\over \sqrt{2}})+o({1\over x})\\
&={1\over x}+o({1\over x})
\end{align}

Comment: What does it mean, ${1 \over x} + o \left( {1 \over x} \right)$?  Doesn't make sense....

Comment: @DavidG.Stork You know little-o notation? It means $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists k\in(0,1), \forall x \in (0,k), |f(x)-{1\over x}|\le\epsilon|{1\over x}|$...

Comment: Yes of course I know the ${\cal o}$ notation.  But you have the same functional form inside and outside of the order.  What if an answer were $g(x) = x + {\cal o}(x)$?  How does this differ from $g(x) = {\cal o}(x)$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In my answer if I write $f(x)=o({1\over x})$, it means $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists k\in(0,1), \forall x \in (0,k), |f(x)|\le\epsilon|{1\over x}|$, which is different from above....

Comment: @DavidG.Stork What they said makes sense... it's $1/x$ plus terms strictly less important than $1/x$ as $x\to0.$ i.e. agrees with your answer. $1/x + O(1)$ would be a more precise answer, and yours below is preciser still. With big O, $1/x + O(1/x)$ wouldn't differ from $O(1/x).$

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  A bit unusual, though, at least compared to the use of ${\cal O}(x)$.